# ReCaptcha for React Native Web, Android and iOS

Tags: react-native, recaptcha

I'm looking for a solution to implement Google ReCaptcha on a React Native application that is also utilizing react native web. We are not using firebase.

So I know how to implement a web version in React and also know how to implement it in React Native for Android and iOS, but I'm in need of a solution that will work seamlessly for all 3 platforms with as minimal conditions as possible... (ie Platform.OS === 'web
', etc)

If anyone has built a solution and is willing to share the approach I would appreciate it.

I am also open to an alternative to ReCaptcha that will prevent robots. I've thought of generating images of math equations and validating the answers server side but I don't really want to reinvent the wheel and would love a drop-in solution that is production ready, if it exists.

Comment: Did you figure out a good solution?

Comment: @John I ended up using text/email 2fa instead